# Correlation Matrix Issues: Can't Convert Variables to Numerics

Tags: r, correlation

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Can you tell me how I can convert int and factor variables to numeric variables in R?
2. Can you tell me why `as.numeric(as.character(df$Account_Global_Region_Cascading_Band))` doesn't work?

**CONTEXT:**
I've converted all of my CSV columns to numbers. I want to run a correlation matrix via [this STHDA tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software). The Error Message below is preventing this. All variables are literally numbers even though their types aren't necessarily.

**ERROR:**

```
> res <- cor(sql_inputs_formatted)
Error in cor(sql_inputs_formatted) : 'x' must be numeric
```

```
 $ Account_Global_Region_Cascading_Band: int  3 3 2 2 2 2
 $ Account_Annual_Revenue_Cascading    : num  5.6e+08 0.0 0.0 0.0 6.1e+06 5.7e+06
 $ Account_Annual_Revenue              : int  1000 50 50 50 50 50
 $ Account_NAICS_Code_Cascading        : int  813000 334000 517919 0 0 0
 $ Account_Employee_Count_Cascading    : Factor w/ 256 levels "10","100","1000",..: 80 23 66 6 88 47
 $ Account_Employee_Count_Band         : int  5000 10001 10001 10001 100 100
 $ Account_Buyer_Industry_Cascading.1  : int  0 4 1 6 6 0
 $ Active_Nodes                        : int  0 10 0 0 0 0
 $ Active_Node_Bands                   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Account_Fit_Score                   : int  14 10 10 10 16 16
 $ Account_Fit_Score_Bands             : int  3 2 2 2 4 4
 $ Predictive_Engagement_Score_Bands   : int  2 2 2 1 2 4
 $ Engaged_People                      : int  3 6 11 1 4 0
 $ Engagement_Minutes_3_mo             : int  4 747 121 10 312 0
 $ Engagement_Minutes_7.days           : int  0 86 0 0 19 0
 $ Engagio_Status_Bands                : int  1 3 3 3 3 4
 $ DF_Total_Funding                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Number_of_People                    : int  8 6 14 1 3 1
 $ Fortune_Rank                        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Expected_Node_Count_Band            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Contact_Job_Level_Band              : int  2 2 1 2 1 2
 $ Contact_Job_Department_Band         : int  6 6 3 6 6 6
 $ Contact_Sphere_Band                 : int  4 2 1 1 1 4
 $ Bizible_Touchpoint_Count            : int  1 6 1 1 1 0
 $ Bizible_Touchpont_Band              : int  2 6 2 2 2 2
 $ Lead_Source_Type_Band               : int  0 0 1 1 1 0
 $ Person.Score                        : int  90 260 35 35 30 20
 $ Person_Score_Band                   : int  4 6 2 2 2 1
 $ Behavior.Score                      : int  40 15 0 0 0 0
 $ Behavior.Score.Band                 : int  2 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Demographic.Score                   : int  25 225 20 20 20 10
 $ Demographic_Score_Band              : int  1 6 1 1 1 1
 $ SQL                                 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
```

```
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Global_Region_Cascading_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Annual_Revenue_Cascading))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Annual_Revenue))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_NAICS_Code_Cascading))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Employee_Count_Cascading))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Employee_Count_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Buyer_Industry_Cascading.1))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Active_Nodes))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Active_Node_Bands))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Fit_Score))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Account_Fit_Score_Bands))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Predictive_Engagement_Score_Bands))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Engaged_People))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Engagement_Minutes_3_mo))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Engagement_Minutes_7.days))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Engagio_Status_Bands))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$DF_Total_Funding))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Number_of_People))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Fortune_Rank))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Expected_Node_Count_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Contact_Job_Level_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Contact_Job_Department_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Contact_Sphere_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Bizible_Touchpoint_Count))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Lead_Source_Type_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Person.Score))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Behavior.Score))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Behavior.Score.Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Demographic.Score))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$Demographic_Score_Band))
as.numeric(as.character(sql_inputs_formatted$SQL))
```

**ATTACHMENT:**
[image]

All the best,
Andrew

Comment: I think you want something like `cor(sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))`

Answer (score 0):

`as.matrix(sql_inputs_formatted)` should work.